# What determines who gets or becomes an MVP?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

This hasn't been asked yet, but what determines how or who gets an MVP award in CS:GO? After a match, there's always a little blurb that first states who got MVP first, and then a random fact (Player X got Y knife kills, Player X lasted Y rounds without dying, etc.).

Do these two factors both "factor" into getting an MVP award? Is it a set percentage of enemies you kill? Is there a priority list (ie, planting bomb, defusing, etc.)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First off, the MVP will always be selected from the winning team. Then the MVP will be selected based on:

1. Person who completed the objective

   - Hostage rescued
   - Bomb planted (and detonated)
   - Bomb defused
   - Arms Race winner
2. If the round was won by a team getting eliminated

   1. Player with most kills on the winning team
   2. Number of assists, if two or more people have the same amount of kills
   3. If the score of kills + assists is still the same the player who joined the server first will be MVP (first out of the ones with equal scores, not out of all players)
3. No MVP

   - Round draw
   - rare, but possible: time runs out and no damage was done on the winning team

Source for most of this: [CS Wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/MVP)

Comment: According to this answer (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132126/what-determines-who-gets-or-becomes-an-mvp/132401#132401) in a duplicate question, 2.3 should be "the player who gets their kills first". However, there is no source neither your nor the other answer.

Comment: @Nico now it has one

Comment: it's a community-run Wiki, I'm not sure it can be considered as reliable source. Note that I don't especially want to be a nitpicker, it's just that I've always been curious about this and I'd like to know for sure. I guess someone should try it against bots once, in order to be definitive. But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @Nico sure it may not be as accurate as developer comments, but it's as close as you can get to reality. People contributing there don't do that to harm others :)

Comment: I still upvoted your answer ;-) It's just that, at least for me, "what some dude said on wikia" isn't a definitive answer. But I guess we'll have to do with it.

Comment: @Nico you're right  ) ...a Wiki isn't exactly the most accurate place on earth, but sometimes there's just no better option than that (or your own personal experience). Especially Valve and HPE really love to keep their secrets :/

Answer (score 3):

MVP is determined by who did the most toward playing the objective, then style, then kills, etc. For instance, blowing the bomb > 1 knife > 1 headshot > 2 kills. If a particular user is going above and beyond for the round, they get the MVP.

Objective (DEfusal or Counter-Strike hostage rescue) > Style of Kills > # of Kills. (Kills trumps style if kills >= half of team. Style trumps Objective if objective not completed. Objective trumps all if completed.)

Source is first-hand experience.

Comment: This is not a definitive answer.

Comment: @Alan Okay I'll edit it to be so, but just remember, Objective > Style > Kills.

Comment: What do you mean by style? And how much is each of these worth? If I were to kill 3 players, and you knife 2, aren't I MVP? What if I kill 5 and you knife 4? What if I kill 2 and get 1 assist and you knife 2? What if I kill the entire team, but you defuse the bomb? If style is a different priority level, what else other than knife kills are style? etc. etc.

Comment: Style is determined as methods of kills, knifes v headshots. If we are on a 6v6 server and you knife 3 and I kill 3 with headshots, the knives trump headshots because of difficulty to perform. but if you knife the whole team, and I diffuse the bomb, **I BELIEVE, THOUGH HAVE NOT TESTED** that I get the MVP because the Objective was not completed because of my action and you assisted the completion and were not the direct occurrence of the result.

I'm at work atm, so I will leave the test plan:

1. Get server with bots, 2. sv_cheats 1, 3. bot_stop 1, 4. knife all bots and let bot defuse bomb.

Comment: I'm interested in trying this too, but I believe your answer is out of order.. Should be Objective > kills > style .. If you are right, the method of kills (style) is the tiebreaker after considering how many kills each player received. In de_ maps Objective can't be tiebroken, since only 1 player plants/defuses. I never play hostage rescue maps, but what if two players rescue a hostage? Is first MVP? Or do both players get objective credit and kills becomes a tiebreaker? (I doubt that). The other thing I'd like to test is player damage outside of assists/kills and its effect.

Comment: Also, does my death affect MVP chances? What if we both kill 2 players, but I die and you do not?

Comment: Death does not count, I can verify that with first hand experience in the kills test plan.

Comment: Style has trumped kills in the past, think style = skill, You are welcome to make the test plan and videos and separate answer if you feel this stongly. My answer stands by my first hand knowledge and no google-fu has presented anything supporting or to the contrary. You are welcome to make a chat room but as I said earlier, I'm unavailable to participate for a few hours. Until then, my answer stands.

Answer (score 3):

The MVP in my experience with competitive play is determined as follows:

- Must be a member of the team that won the round
- If the bomb detonated or was defused, whoever planted/defused.
- Whoever got the most kills. (4 kills guarantee MVP over defuse or plant)
- If players tied for most kills, whoever got their kills first.

Answer (score 1):

By getting MVP:

- Getting most kills among your teammate
- Planting a bomb (If the above one didn't affect this)
- Defusing a bomb (Same as above, I believe)